# How to manually edit the MBR to recover lost partition?

Tags: partitioning, mbr, partition-recovery, hfs+

I have accidentally deleted two [HFS+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus) partitions. I know the start and end sectors of both of them. These partitions are 100% healthy. I can see them in Raise Data Recovery, but testdisk does not see them. How can I manually edit the [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) to restore these partitions from Ubuntu or Windows?

The "sfdisk -l" command in Ubuntu terminal shows:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 60801 cylinders, 255 heads, 63 sectors/track
Warning: extended partition does not start at a cylinder boundary.
DOS and Linux will interpret the contents differently.
Units = cylinders of 8225280 bytes, blocks of 1024 bytes, counting from 0

   Device Boot Start     End   #cyls    #blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1         12+  12747-  12736- 102294528    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda2      12747+  48643-  35896- 288328704    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda3          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
/dev/sda4          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
/dev/sda5      12748+  43870   31123- 249995466    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda6      43871+  48144-   4274-  34324480   83  Linux
/dev/sda7      48145+  48643-    499-   4001792   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Where sda3 and sda4 are these partitions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows FAT/NTFS Low-Level Disk Viewer (Norton DiskEdit alternative)](http://superuser.com/questions/97006/windows-fat-ntfs-low-level-disk-viewer-norton-diskedit-alternative)

Comment: actually, the data presented here is a bit odd. Unless, ofcourse, the size of **sda3** and **sda4** is really less than 8MiB?

Comment: sda3 and sda4 physically were located at the end of the disk. Something like this: sda1, sda2 start, sda 5, sda 6, sda 7, sda2 end, sda3, sda4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, first try this:

> apt-get install -y parted (in case of Debian-based distro)
>
> partprobe
>
> parted /dev/sda
> u s (switches units to sectors)
> p (prints partition table)
> mkpart p **start end** (p - primary, this should be your sda3)
> mkpart p **start end** (should be sda4)

I'd run **partprobe** again after that's done. If it does not work - then yeah, would need to edit the **MBR** manually, I guess.

**Edit**: one thing that occurred to me is that you might run into issues, when **parted** is complaining about injecting partitions with such "out of spec" boundaries.. Well, just delete everything starting from **sda5** and recreate them the same way after the successful addition of **sda3** & **sda4**.

Comment: Ok, that is my question, how do I edit it? From which tool?

Comment: So, what, **parted** did not work or.. ?

Comment: @nik Parted *is* a partition table editor, it is the best tool for editing partitions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sfdisk to add those empty partition, for example

```
sfdisk /dev/sda << EOF
0,381230,0c
381231,84481,0b
465712,,S
EOF
```

Each line has three values the start and the end sector and the third value is the partition type. To use this console mode you need to install a special package. But I don't know if this delete the partition content. I suggest to make a copy with dd.