# Directly edit the hard disk on Windows Vista

Tags: hard-drive, windows-vista

I'm on Windows Vista Home 32bit.

Is there a way to edit the disk the system is on? Hex editors will not edit the hard drive directly. Is there a work around besides BartPE?

Comment: The `dd` utility found on every Linux live CD allows direct access to the data. You could use `dd` to dump a region of the disk to a file, edit the file in a hex editor, and the use `dd` again to copy the data back to the original location.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows FAT/NTFS Low-Level Disk Viewer (Norton DiskEdit alternative)](http://superuser.com/questions/97006/windows-fat-ntfs-low-level-disk-viewer-norton-diskedit-alternative)

Comment: Note that all raw disk edits will require the relevant file system to be dismounted/locked, so there will be no editing the "system" partition from an application running "inside" it. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 6):

- [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) is freeware and lets you (hex-)edit a file or disk at a low level.
- [Disk Explorer](http://www.runtime.org/diskexplorer.htm) (and its NTFS and Linux counterpart) are commercial but not only let you edit a disk at a low level, but it also understands disk structures, so you can view and follow things like directory entries, boot sectors, FAT, $Mft, etc.

Answer (score 2):

On the Windows XP install CD there is a tool called [Dskprobe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736327%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). I'm not near a computer with Vista or Win7 at the moment, but this tool may work under Vista 32 bit as well as XP *(edit to add: tested and found to work under Win7 x64 so it'll probably work under Vista x86.).*

> This GUI tool is a sector editor for drives on computers running
>   Windows XP and Windows Server 2003. A user with local Administrator
>   rights can use DiskProbe to directly edit, save, and copy data on a
>   physical hard drive that is not accessible in any other way.

Dskprobe is also available for download as part of the [Windows XP SP2 Support Tools package](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18546).
[image]